# SortedMap with duplicate keys

Tags: java, processing, sortedmap

I need to sort some objects of a custom class (Face) according to a float returned by a method of the class.

I decided to use a sorted map but I realized that duplicate keys are not returned by the Collection.

This is my code:

```
sorted.clear();
for(Face f : face) {
  sorted.put(f.getFarthestDepth(), f);
}
//Code for printing entries of the sortedTree
for(Map.Entry entry : sorted.entrySet())
  print(entry.getKey() + " ");
println();
```

and on my render method I have:

```
pushMatrix();
translate(center.x, center.y);
for(Map.Entry entry : sorted.entrySet()) {
  Face f = (Face)entry.getValue();
  beginShape();
  fill(255);
  for (Vertex v : f.vertex) {
    vertex(v.x, v.y);
  }
  endShape(CLOSE);
}  
popMatrix();
```

When I print the entries of my tree map I get only 2 values and I need to get 6 with the same key value.

I am using Processing but the code is almost similar to java.

How can I get all Face objects?

Comment: you cannot have multiple objects with same key value in a map.If you want to support duplicate elements consider using list.

Comment: Use a Map<Float, List<Face>> instead of a Map<Float, Face>?

Comment: It seems you have a Collection of Faces. Why don't you implement a Comparator depending on your float value of Face and call `Collection#sort`

Comment: @JBNizet What is the difference? Would I get duplicate key values? What other changes should I make?

Comment: The difference is that for each float, you could be able to sort ALL the faces having this float value, instead of just one. That said, a Map is useful to be able to get a value from a key. But your code never does that. Why do you use a Map in the first place? Why not just a sorted list?

Comment: If you can add Guava library as a dependency then you can use Multimap http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html, if not, then construct the map as @JBNizet suggested

Answer (score 0):

Use Guava's TreeMultiMap with a custom comparator. It keeps list of objects for duplicate keys.